# How to filter one dataframe column values using another dataframe column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tvar

Below is my Dataframe: Df1

```
origin        2001-01-01 00:00:00  2002-01-01 00:00:00  2003-01-01 00:00:00  ...  2009-01-01 00:00:00  2010-01-01 00:00:00   Grand Total
Simulation 1         2.281294e+13                  NaN         1.459444e+20  ...         1.618202e+59         6.811895e+64  1.748673e+72
Simulation 2         2.175246e+13                  NaN         1.711078e+20  ...         1.388109e+59         5.608744e+64  2.106283e+72
Simulation 3         2.280800e+13                  NaN         1.422197e+20  ...         9.737150e+58         2.589176e+64  9.651312e+71
Simulation 4         2.426074e+13                  NaN         1.369407e+20  ...         1.063072e+59         2.921763e+64  1.961873e+71
```

2nd Dataframe : df2

```
 CI           Var 
0  60.0  3.009765e+72 
1  70.0  3.511393e+72 
2  80.0  4.013020e+72 
3  90.5  4.539729e+72
```

below is my code:

```
class cl_test():
    @classmethod
    def resamledtriangle(self,n_sims):
        # Load triangle
        triangle = cl.load_sample('genins')
        # Use bootstrap sampler to get resampled triangles
        bootstrapdataframe = cl.BootstrapODPSample(n_sims = n_sims, random_state=42).fit(triangle).resampled_triangles_

        #converting to dataframe
        resampledtriangledf1 = bootstrapdataframe.to_frame()
        #print(resampledtriangledf1)
        Reserve_val = []
        iter_count=0
    
        while (iter_count < n_sims):
            bg = resampledtriangledf1[resampledtriangledf1.index==iter_count]
            resampledtriangledf = bg.pivot_table(index="origin", columns="development", values="values")
            #print(resamp)
            #final = resampledtriangledf[::-1].bfill().iloc[0]
            final2 = resampledtriangledf.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
            resampledtriangledf = resampledtriangledf.assign(Total = final2.values)
            #resampledtriangledf = resampledtriangledf.append(pd.Series(totTriangleDf1.sum(), name='Total')).append(pd.Series(final, name='Latest Observation'))
            #calculating grand total of each row and column
            #resampledtriangledf['Grand Total'] = resampledtriangledf.sum(axis=1)
            #resampledtriangledf.loc["Grand Total"] = resampledtriangledf.sum() 
            resampledtriangledf = resampledtriangledf.append(pd.Series(resampledtriangledf.sum(), name='Grand Total'))  
            resampledtriangcdfwa1 = resampledtriangledf.shift(-1, axis=1).loc['Grand Total'] / (resampledtriangledf.loc['Grand Total'])
            resampledtriangledf = resampledtriangledf.append(pd.Series(resampledtriangcdfwa1,name='Weighted Average'))
            c = resampledtriangledf.iloc[1][::-1].replace(np.inf, np.nan).dropna().cumprod()
            resampledtriangledf = resampledtriangledf.append(c.rename('CDF'))

            s = resampledtriangledf.iloc[:, :][:-2].copy()
            ultiCalc = pd.DataFrame()
            ultiCalc['Latest']= s['Total']
            ultiCalc['CDF'] = np.flip(resampledtriangledf.loc['CDF'].values) 
            ultiCalc['Ultimate'] = ultiCalc['Latest']*ultiCalc['CDF'] 
            ultiCalc['Unpaid'] = ultiCalc['Ultimate']-ultiCalc['Latest']
            ultiCalc = ultiCalc.append(pd.Series(ultiCalc.sum(), name='Total'))
            #ultiCalc = ultiCalc.iloc[: , :-1]
            iter_count+=1
            Reserve_val.append(ultiCalc['Unpaid'])  


        simulationDf = pd.DataFrame([x for x in Reserve_val]).reset_index(drop=True)
        simulationDf.index = 'Simulation ' + (simulationDf.index + 1).astype(str)
        simulationDf = simulationDf.iloc[: , :-1]
        return simulationDf

    def varmethod(self,CI,simulationDf):
        total = simulationDf['Grand Total'].sum() 
        df = pd.DataFrame(CI,columns=['CI'])
        for value,data in enumerate(CI): #== The enumerate() method adds counter to an iterable and returns it (the enumerate object).
            CI[value]=(data/100)*(total)
        df['Var'] = CI
        print(df)
        return df
```

Here I have to iterate the var values from df2 and compare with grand total column of df dataframe. And create the new dataframe and store all the grand total values which is grater than Var values.
For ex:
First value of Var column is 3.009765e+72. I have to filter all  greater values from grand total of df1 create dataframe for it.
Next we have to filter for second value of Var(3.511393e+72 ) and create dataframe. So on

Comment: please add code to reproduce this example dataframe so that we can reproduce this in our testing environment.

Comment: I meant, "code to produce dataframe with the data as shown in your example.."

Comment: Yes edited my question with my code. @AnuragDhadse

Comment: Will this code be able to reproduce the dataframe as shown in post we can work with? think again?

Comment: Yes @AnuragDhadse

Comment: @AnuragDhadse You can copy the dataframes and try `pd.read_clipboard("\s\s+")`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples#comment60808128_20159305).

Comment: @Mustafa Aydin A huge thanks for understanding the situation and giving me a valuable tip. But this isn't usable on colab

Comment: A list comprehension? `[df1[df1["Grand Total"] > value] for value in df2.Var]`. This should give you a list of dataframes each of which is filtered according to the corresponding value from `df2.Var`.

Comment: Dataframe @MustafaAydın

Comment: I tried your solution but it shows empty dataframe. @MustafaAydın

Comment: Because all the `Grand Total` values are less than the values in `df2.Var`, we should expect empty dataframes, no?

Comment: If condition is true then also it shows empty dataframe.  @MustafaAydın

Comment: I tried with `df2.Var /= 1e5` to make `df.Var` small and then use the code above, and I don't get empty dataframes.

Comment: I din't get. What is that /=le5? @MustafaAydın

Comment: That divides `df2.Var` by 1e5 = 100,000 to make it smaller

Comment: Can we get the each every dataframe count? @MustafaAydın

Comment: Do you mean number of rows of each dataframe?

Comment: Then `len([df1[df1["Grand Total"] > value]) for value in df2.Var]`.

Comment: Your code just reprints the simultaion dataframe thats it. It not filter simulation table based on Var values. @MustafaAydın

Comment: Yeah, if the `Grand Total` values are all larger than values in `df2.Var`, that's what it does.

Comment: We have to check first value of df2.var with all the values of df1.Grand Total. It its true the it just store that row in data frame except this all will to ignore. Then check or second value for df2,var so on. Each and every df1.var it create dataframe according to condition. (df2.var<df1.GrandTotal) @MustafaAydın

Comment: What exactly is your expected output for the `df1` and `df2` you have in the question? Can you please put it in the question too?

Comment: Now please check i update with expected output.  @MustafaAydın

Comment: `9.651312e+71` is less than all values in `df2.Var`, why is it in the output?

Comment: Ya But I just used to explain to you. I will delete it. If > the only it display the that grand total value. Here not only 4 simultions. Simulation limit entering by user. So it can be any number of simulation.@MustafaAydın

Comment: Okay, so `[df1.loc[df1["Grand Total"] > value, "Grand Total"] for value in df2.Var]`?

Comment: Thank You . I think its working. How to count total number of values select. For each dataframe? @MustafaAydın

Comment: Without using df2.Var /= 1e5 result will be the empty dataframe . Why? @MustafaAydın

Comment: Because no `Grand Total` satisfies the condition.

Comment: for the number of values selected: `[len(df1.loc[df1["Grand Total"] > value, "Grand Total"]) for value in df2.Var]`

Comment: I want count result in separate line. Not in same line. I  need like sum of each dataframe and count of each dataframe as welll.@MustafaAydın

Comment: What do you mean by "separate line"? What does the code for counts give and you don't like it? What do you mean by "sum" of each dataframe: sum of all entires or sum of rows of each dataframe? What is count of each dataframe? I'm sorry but unless you put what you need as the expected output in the question clearly, I'm afraid I cannot help further.